# Invalid argument error with NSMutableString?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmutablestring, invalidargumentexception

I have the following statement in my program:

```
[operateAns replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(start, end-start) withString:[answer stringValue]];
```

operateAns is initialized in the following way where calc is an NSMutableString:

```
operateAns = calc;
```

and I am getting the following error

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with replaceCharactersInRange:withString:'
```

any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this at time of assignment.

> operateAns = [calc mutableCopy];

Comment: This worked, but could you expand on why this must be done even though they are already mutable strings?

Comment: @JDodle you are taking that as NSMutableString but probably where you initialise your calc, you get NSString. you can check by debugging what kind object is calc.